# Why does two or more slick sliders not work in the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I want to use two identical slick sliders, the first slider works but the other one does not work. Can someone please help me correct the invalid code?

```html
<section class="center slider">
  <div><a href="#"><img src="Desert.jpg"></a></div>
  <div><a href="#"><img src="Desert.jpg"></a></div>
  <div><a href="#"><img src="Desert.jpg"></a></div>
  <div><a href="#"><img src="Desert.jpg"></a></div>
</section>
<section class="center1 slider">
  <div><a href="#"><img src="Desert.jpg"></a></div>
  <div><a href="#"><img src="Desert.jpg"></a></div>
  <div><a href="#"><img src="Desert.jpg"></a></div>
  <div><a href="#"><img src="Desert.jpg"></a></div>
</section>
```

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $(".center").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  });
  $(".center1").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me, please create a working example of the problem

Comment: This is all the code.
The rest of the code is just the css code.
Only the first slick works and the second slick does not work